# How do I setup ssl on a rails 4 app? (nginx + passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, passenger

I have a staging rails app running with passenger on nginx. I want to secure the connections with SSL. I have read a lot of resources online but I have yet to make it run on SSL.

So far, my server block on nginx.conf is:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     listen 443 default deferred;
     server_name example.com;
     root /home/deploy/app/public;
     passenger_enabled on;

     passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;

     ssl on;
     ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
     ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/server.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
 }
```

The site is running but not on HTTPS.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've just made the decission to go with SSL myself and found an article on the [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04) site on how to do this. It might be the `listen 443 default deferred;`, which according to that article should be `ssl` not `deferred`.

Here's the nginx block they use;

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  listen 443 ssl;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name your_domain.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I now have my own site running on SSL. Along with the above I just told Rails to force SSL. In your production environment config;

```
# ./config/environments/production.rb
config.force_ssl = true
```

Optionally, you can add these setting in the `nginx.conf`;

```
http {
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
  keepalive_timeout 70;
}
```

**UPDATE: 2015-09**

Since I wrote this answer I've added a few of extra things to my `nginx` config, which I believe everyone should also include. Add the following to your `server` block;

```
server {
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
}
```

The first three lines (`ssl_prefer_server_ciphers`, `ssl_protocols`, `ssl_ciphers`) are the most import as they make sure you have a good strong SSL settings.

The `X-Frame-Options` prevents your site from being included via the `<iframe>` tags. I expect most people will benefit from including this setting.

Comment: I have done same setup but Rails do not start however if I run passenger start then it run

Comment: Did you need to run your passenger with ssl on ?

Comment: with the above settings you just need to make sure to set `passenger_enabled on`.

Comment: I somehow get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in chrome with the above configuration :(

Comment: Would this fallback to TLSv1 if the browser doesn't support newer versions?